# Yaml configuration list of objects to properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, yaml, properties-file

I'm trying to convert the following yaml configuration for SAML2 security to and equivalent properties file.

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          xyz:
            signing:
              credentials:
              - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/xyz.pem"
                private-key-location: "classpath:saml/xyz.key"
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: xyz
              sso-url: xyz.com
              verification: 
                credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/xyz.pem"
```

It contains lists and it's not obvious how to convert it to properties.
I couldn't find much online about it.

This portion of the config file configures the following class:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.saml2.Saml2RelyingPartyProperties
```

From the spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar.

Comment: can you show the Java class matching this yaml

Comment: The class is deep inside saml2 library. The class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.saml2.Saml2RelyingPartyProperties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. This should work

```
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.xyz.signing.credentials[0].certificate-location=classpath:saml/xyz.pem
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.xyz.signing.credentials[0].private-key-location=classpath:saml/xyz.key
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.xyz.identityprovider.entity-id=xyz
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.xyz.identityprovider.sso-url=xyz.com
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.xyz.identityprovider.verification.credentials[0].certificate-location=classpath:saml/xyz.pem
```

Comment: The answer was almost correct. I made small corrections to the identityprovider names and removed quotes.